# How to exclude files extension from os.walk

Tags: python-2.6, os.walk

I would like to search files, except those which contain .txt file. How to do that ?
At the moment my code is searching for files with .txt extension on it. How to do an opposite?

```
src = raw_input("Enter source disk location: ")
src = os.path.abspath(src)
print "src--->:",src
for dir,dirs,_ in os.walk(src, topdown=True):

    file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.txt"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter your files with a list comprehension:

```
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in files if not f.endswith('.txt')]
```

I removed the `topdown=True` argument; it is the default.

Don't use `glob.glob()` in combination with `os.walk()`; both methods query the Operating System for the filenames in a directory. You *already* have those filenames at hand in the third value from each iteration over `os.walk()`.

If you want to skip the whole directory, use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to see if there are any matching files, then use `continue` ignore this directory:

```
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    if any(f.endswith('.txt') for f in files):
        continue  # ignore this directory

    # do something with the files here, there are no .txt files.
    files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in files]
```

If you want to ignore this directory *and all its descendants*, clear out the `dirs` variable too using slice assignment:

```
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    if any(f.endswith('.txt') for f in files):
        dirs[:] = []  # do not recurse into subdirectories
        continue      # ignore this directory

    # do something with the files here, there are no .txt files.
    files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in files]
```

Comment: And what if .txt files exist in subdirectories for example data----> folder -----> test.txt and i want to exclude subdirectory only ?

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski: so you want to skip any directory that has a `.txt` file in it?

Comment: Exactly :) this is my goal

Comment: i only want list of subdirectories which do not have .txt in them. My goal is to filter those subdirectories. Furthermore i want to move them to other position. I already did it for directories which contains .txt in them.

Comment: so to move directories without .txt on it i should use shutil in this loop ?

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski: are there subdirectories too? Perhaps collect the directory paths in a list, then in a next step move all those matched directories.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.I am appreciate your help. Thanks man :)